# Laravel 5.1 Eloquent ORM, GroupBy, Sum, Join

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Hi I want the data as shown in the below image.

[image]

*My Table in the database is as follow:*

```
analytics:

id | article_id | country_code | sessions | revenue | date
```

When I'm doing this its firing lots of queries, how can I join, sum and groupBy in a single query to get the data as shown in figure.

I want the data groupBy **Dates** and then inside it I want the data groupBy **Articles** and sum of **Revenue** and also the sum of **Sessions**

What I have tried is:

```
$analytics = Analytics::groupBy('date')
        ->selectRaw('sum(revenue) as total_revenue, date, sum(sessions) as total_sessions')
        ->orderBy('date', 'DESC')
        ->get();
```

After this I have done ajax call according to the dates. But I want it by joining articles and analytics table. Also need the sum of revenues and sessions after grouping it by dates and by articles.

I want the best Optimized Query for this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please show what you've tried, giving you "the best Optimized Query for this" is not what we're here for.

Comment: @Fester please check the question again I'm updating with what I have tried